# read a file and execute each line as command using ansible

Tags: shell, ansible

I want to write a playbook for following scenario:
reads a text file which has linux commands written it,
executes them one by one,
aborts if any command fails to execute,
and
if I correct the command and run the playbook again it should execute from where it was aborted (instead of executing from beginning)

sample file: `sample.txt`

```
echo "hello world"  
df -h  
free -m  
mkdir /tmp/`hostname`_bkp  
touch /tmp/`hostname`_bkp/file{1..5}  
mvn -version  
echo "directory and files created"  
echo "Bye.!"
```

So for example if `mvn -version` fails to execute then ansible should abort.

How can achieve scenario through ansible?

Comment: Is there any particular reason to execute the commands from a file, and not just create task for each command?

Comment: As there are lot of commands to be executed so I thought putting them consolidated in a text file and reading them line by line would be an idea.

Comment: actually it is better to use a tasks file for that - every command is a task, which will be executed. You can set conditions, loops, actions on success/unsuccessful completion of tasks and so on. I will draft an example with your commands and post them in an answer. Meanwhile, if you want a more useful/meaningful commands to be executed, please edit your questions - I'm not sure what exactly is the benefit of `echo "Hello World!"` for you :)

Comment: I just gave an example that my text file looks like this.
Actual commands may be tested once I get any working code. :)

Answer (score 2):

Bellow is an example playbook, which executes a number of simple tasks.

```
---
 - hosts: localhost
   tasks:
    - name: say hi
      shell: echo "Hello, World!"

    - name: do df -h
      shell: df -h
      register: space

    - name: show the output of df -h
      debug: var=space

    - name: do free -m
      shell: free -m
      register: memory
      ignore_errors: yes

    - name: show memory stats
      debug: var=memory

    - name: create /tmp/"hostname"_bkp
      file: dest=/tmp/{{ ansible_nodename }}_bkp state=directory

    - name: create files
      file: dest=/tmp/{{ ansible_nodename }}_bkp/file{{ item }} state=touch
      with_items:
       - 1
       - 2
       - 3
       - 4
       - 5
```

It creates a directory and files at the desired location. You can also set ownership, permissions, which fit better your requirements.

`ansible_nodename` is an ansible fact (a variable), which gets collected at the beginning of a play.

You can see more information about the ansible file module [here](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/file_module.html). Please have a look at the other ansible modules - they are plenty, easy to learn and powerful.

Comment: Thanks for your playbook, Here we have only a sample 4 or 5 commands. what if I have more than 20/25/50 commands then what would be the best approach through ansible.?

Comment: You can create roles (e.g. role `apache`, which will have few tasks file - one `main` which includes other tasks files (install nginx, deploy configuration files, harden apache), or role for ssh - tasks file which installs and hardens sshd. It is a common and a good practice to follow such structure of your playbooks. I really advise you to go through http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/intro_getting_started.html